# How to login HashiCorp Vault using curl command

Tags: curl, hashicorp-vault

How to login HashiCorp Vault using curl command?

am looking curl command equal to # vault login

Thanks
Bala

Comment: Which auth method are you trying to use? Each of them requires different set of arguments. For example to login via Github token: ```curl --request POST --data '{ "token": "<token-copied-from-github>"}' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/github/login``` You can find more about Github login method here: https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/github/#login

Comment: vault login using token

Answer (score 2):

How to log on depends on the method of logon you want to use. Here's a curl request to logon with `myusername`/`mypassword` via LDAP:

`curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "password": "mypassword" }' https://vaultserverhostname/v1/auth/ldap/login/myusername`

This returns json, which when "prettied" looks something like this:

```
{
    "auth": {
        "accessor": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "client_token": "s.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "entity_id": "ff20aa70-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "lease_duration": 2764800,
        "metadata": {
            "username": "myusername"
        },
        "orphan": true,
        "policies": [
            "default",
            "ldap-users-policy"
        ],
        "renewable": true,
        "token_policies": [
            "default",
            "ldap-users-policy"
        ],
        "token_type": "service"
    },
    "data": {},
    "lease_duration": 0,
    "lease_id": "",
    "renewable": false,
    "request_id": "69887f78-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXX",
    "warnings": null,
    "wrap_info": null
}
```

Source: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/ldap#sample-request-10

The same for UserPass method: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/userpass#sample-request

Whatever request you use, you get a token in the json response (or an error), you can then use the token for further Vault interactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Vault CLI command and you just need to know how to do the same operation through a curl call, you can run the CLI command with --output-curl-string

https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412233931667-Translate-Vault-CLI-commands-to-HTTP-API

Answer (score 0):

What `vault login token=<token-id>` does, it creates `$HOME/.vault-token` file with `<token-id>`. Then each time you use `vault` command this token is set by the `vault` client as a value to `X-Vault-Token` HTTP header in each request to the server.

However, when you use `curl` you have to set this header on every request (see [documentation here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/token/#authentication) and [this one](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/#authentication))

So each `curl` command will have header command line option set to following value: `-H "X-Vault-Token: <your-token-id>"`.

For example to read `/secret/foo`

```
curl \
    -H "X-Vault-Token: f3b09679-3001-009d-2b80-9c306ab81aa6" \
    -X GET \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/foo
```